# How can I pack a Date and Time into 32-bits?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I have a date represantation with the following order in order to fit an int. The date represantation should be

```
year   : 6 bits
month  : 5 bits
day    : 5 bits
hours  : 4 bits
minutes: 6 bits
seconds: 6 bits
```

All the dates should be fit into an `Unit32 date`

```
[year(5bits),month(5bits),day(6bits),hours(4bits),minutes(6bits),seconds(6bit)]
           
UInt32 date = 0;
date= date| (UInt32) (DateTime.Now.Year%2000)<< 26;
date= date| ((uint)DateTime.Now.Month << 22);    
date= date| (uint)DateTime.Now.Day << 17;
date= date| ((uint)DateTime.Now.Hour << 15);
date= date| ((uint)DateTime.Now.Minute << 6);
date= date| ((uint)DateTime.Now.Second);
string binary = Convert.ToString(date, 2);
```

Above i have tried some bitwise operation but the result doestn satisfy. what i am missing or what should i do?

For Example current date is: 2021.55.10 13:55:06
Binary conversion above code 1010100110101101000110111000011 hex mean 54D6 8DC3 that means  Thursday, 1 January 1970 06:01:58 but it should be today's date

thanks.

Comment: "the result doestn satisfy." isn't exactly the clearest description of *what problem you're having*.

Comment: What have you done to try and debug your problem? The first step would be to take those components one at a time: set the year to some value and the rest to 0, and check that the result has the right bits in the right place. Do the same for the rest.

Comment: The shift constants you're using don't look right though (especially 15 and 17 around hour and 22 and 26 around month)

Comment: You have `date` and `data` (`a` vs `e`) confused on line 6.

Comment: Also, because you use `DateTime.Now` on every line, you might end up with some really weird numbers if the time ticks over to a new hour/minute/day halfway through the calculation.

Comment: You should not use `DateTime.Now` repeatedly in the same method - you need to store a snapshot value in a variable first, this is because `DateTime.Now` can change between calls (e.g. if your code starts at `23:59:59.999` but ends at `00:00:00.001`.

Comment: You should use a bitwise `AND` mask to select only the relevant bits from each component.

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that `1010100110101101000110111000011` is in 1970? The first 5 bits are `01010` (the value you gave misses the leading `0`) which is decimal 10. Wrong, but not in 1970. (It's wrong because the first shift should be `<< 27`)

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use Unix-time? (with resolution adjusted to account for only 32-bits of space). That would be a lot more saner...

Comment: @canton7 That is tre but it takes as 101001 i mean doesnt count msb 0

Comment: @Nazim "doesn't count MSB 0"? Explain.

Comment: @Dai Yes there is a reason memory reason which i cant use unix epox time

Comment: And where did `101001` come from?

Comment: @canton7 after  "date= date|(UInt32) (dateTime.Year%2000)<< 26; " shifting 10101 directly appear

Comment: 4 bits to represent a value between 0 and 23? Good luck with that one!

Comment: There's a lot about this question that's really unclear. I suggest you go back and provide a [mcve] (with a fixed `DateTime` value rather than using `DateTime.Now`, so we can all discuss and reproduce the exact same value). Show exactly what you expect and why, and what you got.

Comment: I was asking about the `101001` in your last comment. Yes `10101` is 21, which is correct for the year, but it's appearing in the **wrong place**. It should be at bits 27-31 (if you start counting at 0), but yours appear a bits 26-30

Comment: @canton7 thanks i am going to check

Comment: @Nazim That's incorrect. **You can use Unix time**, just with a lower resolution.

Comment: Note that your code appears to be actually allowing 9 bits for the "minute" part and only  2 bits for the "hour" part...

Comment: @JonSkeet thank you very much sir. i am going to correct this

Comment: You probably switched Month and Hour. It should be 4 bits for month and 5 for hour

Comment: Take a look at [BitVector32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32), you may find it easier to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a few problems with your scheme:

```
year   : 6 bits - 0 to 63
month  : 5 bits - 0 to 31
day    : 5 bits - 0 to 31
hours  : 4 bits - 0 to 15 
minutes: 6 bits - 0 to 63
seconds: 6 bits - 0 to 63
```

- The main problem is that your scheme only uses 4 bits for hours - so it cannot represent times between 4pm and midnight (i.e. hours 16 through 23).
- Secondarily, your scheme is *inefficient* because it wastes bits (there's `0-59` seconds in a minute, not `0-63`).
- ...which means your scheme can represent invalid values, such as the 63rd second of the 63rd minute of the 15th hour of the 31st of February - which isn't a real date+time.

Rather than reinventing the wheel, why not use something like Unix time? (i.e. simply the number of seconds since an epoch).

> Yes there is a reason memory reason which i cant use unix epox time

...so you need to fit the value into 32-bits. That's fine because you **can** use Unix time with 32-bit values. Of course this means [you'll run into the Year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) but there's a few possible different solutions:

- You can use a lower resolution.

  - e.g. 2-second or 1-minute resolution.
- You can use a different epoch (base offset).

  - **signed** 32-bit Unix time uses `1970-01-01 00:00:00` with a max date+time value of `2038-01-19 03:14:07`.
  - Unsigned 32-bit Unix time has a maximum of `2106-02-07 06:28:15`.
  - If you use an epoch of `2000-01-01 00:00:00` with unsigned 32-bit integers then you have a max value of `2136-02-07 14:28:15`.
  - This range of 135 full years **is significantly better** than your scheme because your scheme uses 6 bits for the year, which is 0-63, and last time I checked, 135 is greater than 63.

So here's a ready-made copy'n'pastable implementation of 32-bit Unix-time with an epoch of `2000-01-01 00:00:00`:

```
private const Int64 YEAR_2000 = 946713600; // The year where there are no elephants. There is also no unethical treatment of elephants.

private static readonly DateTimeOffset _maxValueForUnsigned32Bits = DateTimeOffset( YEAR_2000 + UInt32.MaxValue ); // 2136-02-07 14:28:15

static UInt32 GetTimeAsUInt32( DateTimeOffset dt )
{
    if (dt.Year < 2000 || dt > _maxValueForUnsigned32Bits  ) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( paramName: nameof(dt), actualValue: dt, message: "Must be between 2000 and 2136-02-07 14:28:15 inclusive." );

    Int64  unixFrom2000_64 = dt.ToUnixTimeSeconds() - YEAR_2000;
    // `unixFrom2000_64` *will always fit in 32-bits* due to the year range check above, and subtracting the new epoch.

    UInt32 unixFrom2000_32 = (UInt32)unixFrom2000_64;
    return unixFrom2000_32;
}

static DateTimeOffset GetTimeFromUInt32( UInt32 value )
{
    Int64 asUnixTime = value + YEAR_2000;
    return DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds( asUnixTime );
}
```

Usage:

```
DateTimeOffset now = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow; // WARNING: Using `Now` instead of `UtcNow` will include an offset value that will not be persisted.
Console.WriteLine( "Now: {0}", now );

UInt32 myTime = GetTimeAsUInt32( now );
Console.WriteLine( "As UInt32: {0:D}", myTime );

DateTimeOffset decoded = GetTimeFromUInt32( myTime );
Console.WriteLine( "Decoded from UInt32: {0}", decoded );
```

Gives me this output:

> Now: 10/03/2021 11:26:43 +00:00
> As UInt32: 668662003
> Decoded from UInt32: 10/03/2021 11:26:43 +00:00